# How does the Berserker war end?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, berserker

I read a bunch of short stories and novellas in the berserker series by Fred Saberhagen, but I can't recall if any stories detail the end of the war. I couldn't find any definitive info online either.

Has anyone read the "final" sequential story in the series? If so, which one is it - I have yet to get some closure!

Comment: My money's on the Giant, Intelligent Killing Machines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last story appears to be 1979's *Berserker Man*, since it tells of the development of a final weapon for destroying the berserkers.  Saberhagen continued to write berserker novels afterwards, but (for some of them, at least) there are indications that they do not take place later than *Berserker Man*.  In particular, *Berserker Star* mentions explicitly that some (but not all) of the events from *Berserker Man* have already taken place.

I'm not really sure that *Berserker Man* is that fitting an ending for the berserker saga; I don't think I've ever found anyone who thought it was one of Saberhagen's best books.  However, it is the ending he wrote.

Comment: I am not sure that Berserker Man is the end or finale of the series.  Berserker stories and novels were published for decades after 1979, and a Berserker website suggests reading them in the order they were published - the creator of the site didn't mention and so apparently didn't believe that the stories published later happened before Berserker Man.  Thus I suspect that further investigation is needed for a definite answer.

Comment: In most cases, there is nothing to distinguish which order the stories take place; there are only occasional references that allow an overall chronology to be constructed.  I mentioned the one case I remembered very clearly (from _Berserker Star_) that did identify when the story took place, which happened to me in the middle of _Berserker Man_.